# I want to know the size of Amazon S3 bucket by using c# code .how to get s3 bucket size using c# code?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to know the size of Amazon S3 bucket by using c# code .

is this possible by using c# coding or not.

or it will be only done using AWS CLI

Comment: Max size or current items total size? If later - loop all items in bucket, calculate total size

Comment: cureent subdirectory size which is per user

Comment: I did not get any answer but get one way to handle it, in which when i uploading files to amazon s3 bucket i also stores filename, file.contentlength as size and some other details in one table so i can calculate total size of bucket or subdirectory in bucket by adding the all sizes of files.

the files are stored in bytes so you have to convert it to other formats like mb or gb whichever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No iteration! It is slow and will cost you money.

S3 metrics are published to Cloudwatch:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/s3-metricscollected.html

Use C# or whatever SDK to read this metric from Cloudwatch. `BucketSizeBytes` is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for the answer Çağatay Gürtürk but i don't want to spend money for it

Comment: what money are you talking about?

Comment: I did not get any answer but get one way to handle it, in which when i uploading files to amazon s3 bucket i also stores filename, file.contentlength as size and some other details in one table so i can calculate total size of bucket or subdirectory in bucket by adding the all sizes of files.

the files are stored in bytes so you have to convert it to other formats like mb or gb whichever you want.

Comment: for cloudwatch namespace

Comment: i didnot get method how to use cloudwatch

Comment: Cloudwatch is free. Open cloudwatch console and you will see those metrics there already.

Comment: ohh then sorry i will try it

Comment: i dont want to use any console or CLI, i  want the size using only in c# code

Comment: Well I've shown to you how to do it, I'll not write your code.

Comment: yes, it's true but i want the size only by using c# code

Comment: @ÇağatayGürtürk, the point of this site is to write the code for the asker. You have failed to answer the question.